# Why forEach(System.out::println) works but map(System.out::println) fails?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am doing the Streams tutorial exercises (from Oracle) and wondered why I am getting this compiler error (Eclipse IDE).

```
Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)
```

my code

```
/**
  * Create a new list with all the strings from original list converted to 
  * lower case and print them out.
  */
private void exercise1() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
        "The", "Quick", "BROWN", "Fox", "Jumped", "Over", "The", "LAZY", "DOG");

    list.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).map(System.out::println);
}
```

I also tried `peek(System.out::println)` but it did not print out anything.
I don't understand why `forEach(System.out::println)` works but `map(System.out::println)` fails.

Comment: because `map` wants a function that returns a value and `forEach` does not.

Comment: Proper way to do it using _map_ would be to collect the output and print that. `List<String> collect = list.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: I also tried `peek(System.out::println)` but it did not print out anything.

Comment: That is because `peek` is a non-terminal operation, which doesn't do anything until data is pulled from the stream by a terminal operation.

Answer (score 4):

`map` is intended to, well, map every input A to a result B.

System.out.println(String) returns `void`, i. e. nothing. Thus, it is not suitable as a parameter for `map`.

Even if it allowed it, `map` is not a terminal operation. All streams must end with a terminal operation else they will do nothing.

Comment: I had also tried `peek` but it did not work.

Comment: @likejudo `peek` isn't a terminal operation. You **need** a terminal operation for a stream to be functional. No terminal operation ==> no computation. `forEach` is terminal. `peek`, `map`, `filter` aren't. Read the docs.